# Why do pointers behave differently with ints vs strings in C

Tags: c, pointers, printf, malloc, dereference

I'm learning C right now and am trying to understand why the first snippet of code below works but the second one doesn't.

Here I create a `char*` and assign a string to it (this works fine):

```
int main(void)
{
    char *s = malloc(strlen("Hello!") + 1);
    s = "Hello!\0"; //Why am I able to do this without dereferencing (i.e., *s)?
    printf("%s\n", s); //Why don't I need to dereference s here?
}
```

Here I create an int* and assign a value to it (this one doesn't work):

```
int main(void)
{
    int *i = malloc(sizeof(int));
    i = 5; //I get that this doesn't work because I'm not dereferencing i. Why does the above code with 's' not have the same issue?
    printf("%i\n", i); //I also understand what the issue is here. What confuses me is why the printf above doesn't have the same issue.
}
```

For `i = 5` vs. `s = "Hello!"`, I'm guessing there's some difference in how string literals are passed vs ints (but I'm not completely sure what it is).

For the two different uses of `printf`, I'm a bit more confused. If I pass `s` to `printf`, shouldn't it just print out the address of `s` rather than the actual string?

Comment: A `char*` is a pointer to a char. If you try using a `char*` with individual chars, it'll work the same way as an `int*` does with ints.

Comment: Note that you leak memory in the first example.  You'd really notice the problem if you tried to free the space you allocated — because you've overwritten the pointer returned by `malloc()` with a new value that points to the constant string.  (The `\0` in the string is superfluous, incidentally.) You need to use `strcpy(s, "Hello");` to do what you intend.

Comment: Because there is implicit conversion from arrays to pointers in C. It's confusing to beginners.

Comment: using `=` with a pointer means *point the pointer to...*  . Not "copy this thing to where the pointer is pointing".

Comment: `"Hello\0"` is `char*`, so assignment to another `char*` works. `5` is `int`, so assignment to `int*` does weird things. In a bit more detail, `"Hello\0"` will reserve a 7-character array, fill it with `H, e, l, l, o, \0, \0`, and yield the pointer to the first element (`H`).

Comment: You are able to do `s = "Hello!\0";` because you are simply assigning `s` the address of the *string-literal* `"Hello!\0"`.

Comment: @M.M in the case of my example wouldn't `s = "Hello\0"` be an issue because I am essentially telling the program to "point the pointer to" something that is not an "location" in the memory? Or is it that "Hello!" is passed as a char[ ] which, in turn, is passed as a pointer to some place in the memory? (based on your two comments seems like the latter)

Comment: @rahimftd `"Hello\0"` is a location; it has type `char[7]` .

Comment: @rahimftd In the first one, think of it this way -- ignore the `malloc`, and think of it as `char *s = "Hello!\0";` Also, when you make the assignment `s = "Hello!\0";`, after calling `malloc`, you have just lost the pointer to the block of memory you create with `malloc` causing a memory leak -- there is no way to free that block of memory until you exit.

Comment: Regarding `printf`, it chooses what to do according to the format selector. `%p` or `%ld` or even `%i` would print the pointer (or the numeric value thereof, or the value when coerced to integer's size). `%s` instructs `printf` to take the pointer and print the string there.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - Makes sense. Does = always assign the address for non-primitives?

Comment: It is so, in C (given that all non-primitives are pointers).

Comment: @rahimftd That's where you have to be careful. A *string-literal* is referenced using a pointer (i.e. the address of the first character/element), so a direct assignment with `s` works. If it were a number, then you would have to assign the address `a = 7;`, then `s = &a`, etc..

Comment: @Amadan "all non-primitives are pointers" is false. In fact nothing is a pointer except for pointers themself.

Comment: @Hurkyl no, it's an array of non-const `char`. See section 6.4.5/6 of C11. `s = "Hello!\0"` does not require any special rule.  You might be mixing up C with C++ where what you said would be correct.

Comment: @M.M: You might have noticed the "non-" in my comments... "no primitives are pointers except for pointers themself" in no way contradicts what I said. (Your point about arrays not being pointers but implicitly converting to them is valid.)

Comment: @Amadan OK, edited my comment. `struct s { int x; };` would be an example of a non-primitive that's not a pointer. I'm not sure what point you were trying to make.

Comment: @M.M, It was a simple answer to "Does = always assign the address for non-primitives?". It did ignore the distinction between pointers and things that implicitly convert to pointers, and if I could edit the comment I would.

Comment: @rahimftd `=` always assigns the value. It never assigns the address.  Perhaps you are mentally mixing up *a pointer* with *the thing a pointer is pointing to*.  The value of a pointer is the address of the thing being pointed to.

Comment: @M.M.: Interesting. And you're allowed to modify the contents of (the underlying array of a) C string literal? I had not known that C differed from C++ in that regard. I actually find this distinction a little disconcerting.

Comment: @Hurkyl no, you're not allowed to modify the contents. Nevertheless, they don't have `const` type. A historical wart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main(void)
{
    char *s = malloc(strlen("Hello!") + 1);
    s = "Hello!\0"; //Why am I able to do this without dereferencing (i.e.,*s)?
    printf("%s\n", s); //Why don't I need to dereference s here?
}
```

This will work with integers:

```
int main(void)
{
    int *i = malloc(sizeof(int));
    i = (int *) 5; //I get that this doesn't work because I'm not dereferencing i. Why does the above code with 's' not have the same issue?
    printf("%i\n", (int) i); //I also understand what the issue is here. What confuses me is why the printf above doesn't have the same issue.
}
```

You just need the casts because `5` is not a pointer while `"Hello!\0"` is. In both cases, you just throw away the return value of `malloc` because you set the pointer to point to something else.

So the short answer is that they don't behave differently. You're just using matching types in one case (`s` is a pointer to char and `"Hello!\0"` is convertible to a pointer to char) and mismatched types in the second (`5` is an integer while `i` is a pointer to an integer).

Comment: To be clear, `"Hello!\0"` is an array, not a pointer; however there is implicit conversion from array to pointer in C. It's important to understand this.